# Не получается вывести картинки

Tags: html, mvc, img

Не получается вывести картинку. 
получил путь`'C:/Server/data/htdocs/bwt/public/img/5ae1c68e8fe7e5.01671273.jpg'`
 вставил
`<img scr="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/public/img/'.$value['photo']; ?>" alt="">` но картинки нету =( Использую mvc. Может в ней проблема ?. Я уже напрямую путь получил, но картинка не выводится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы указываете адрес файла на жестком диске (к этому адресу могут обратится Ваши скрипты на этом сервере. Но не как пользователь по URI). Попробуйте указать:

```
<img scr="/bwt/public/img/'.$value['photo']; ?>" alt='' />
```

Comment: css подключаю так и работает `<link href="/public/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">` пытаюсь так же и картинку `<img scr="/public/img/one.jpg'" alt='' />` не работает.

Comment: Andrii, а что консоль( в браузере) пишет?